# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'AutoFill' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datatables, autofill

I am using jquery datatables 1.10 with ASP.NET 4.5. The code works with no issues when debugging. When I run it, it doesn't fill the data in table and leaves as empty data set. This error showed up in FireBug.

Code:

```
        $('#dtGroups').dataTable({
            "oLanguage": {
                "sZeroRecords": "No records to display",
                "sSearch": "Search "
            },
            "aLengthMenu": [[25, 50, 100, 150, 250, 500, -1], [25, 50, 100, 150, 250, 500, "All"]],
            "iDisplayLength": 25,
            "bSortClasses": false,
            "bStateSave": false,
            "bPaginate": true,
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "bDestroy": true,
            "bJQueryUI": false,
            "sAjaxSource": "<%= ResolveUrl("~/Handler/GetData") %>",
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bDeferRender": true,
            "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {

            },
            "aoColumnDefs": [
                {
                    "bVisible": false,
                    "aTargets": [0]                 

                },
                {
                    "aTargets": [1],  
                    "mData": null,
                    "mRender": function (data, type, row) {                            
                        var enc = encodeURI(row[1]);
                        return "<a href='SomePage.aspx?qs="+enc+"'>" + row[1] + "</a>";
                    }

                }
            ],                
            "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                var jsonAOData = JSON.stringify(aoData);
                $.ajax({
                    "dataType": 'json',
                    "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "url": sSource,
                    "data": "{ jsonAOData : '" + jsonAOData + "' }",
                    "success":
                                function (result) {
                                    var json = jQuery.parseJSON(result.d);
                                    console.log(json);
                                    fnCallback(JSON.parse(result.d))
                                },
                    "error":
                        function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert(XMLHttpRequest + ": Error: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + ", " + textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);
                        }
                });
            }
    });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: does server side receive jsonAOData correctly? I don't understand why you `JSON.stringify(aoData)` and then mount a string manually after in `"data": "{ jsonAOData : '" + jsonAOData + "' }"`

Comment: Yes. Server side receives jsonAOData correctly. It works when debugging. It fails when running with no debugging though.

Comment: so when running it's still receiving jsonAOData correctly?

Comment: Yes. It still receives jsonAOData correctly. And now I am getting a new error "TypeError: $.fn.dataTable is undefined".

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation for options http://datatables.net/reference/option/

Also read how to convert your options to datatables 1.10. https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert

`fnServerData` is not an option datatables accepts.